# Object juxtaposition by path command in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my successful attempt to arrange ten circles in a circular formation by `\foreach` command:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]

\foreach \x in {1, ..., 10} 
    \draw[yellow] (\x * 36:10) circle (1.0);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I would like to do the same stuff, but with the other approach, in which a path is generated and the objects will supposed to be juxtaposed along that...

Would you please share some idea to do that?...

Kind regards

Comment: What other approach are you talking about?

Comment: Could you clarify two points? (1) Generating a path where? As in, a circle that connects the smaller circles? (2) by juxtaposed you mean [like this](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/images/5e71a2e5f3796075.png)?

Comment: I am eager to define a circular path by `\path` command and place that circles on that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use decorations

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[decoration={
  markings,
  mark={between positions 0 and 1 step 0.1 with={\draw (0,0) circle (2mm);}}
  },decorate] (0,0) arc (90:-40:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution... The code with this value:  `(0,0) arc (0:360:2cm)` is exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: @Ordenador My pleasure. `(0,0) circle (2cm)` would also do.